# left aligned content in centered block (responsive layout)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So, I'm working on the same kind of thing and having a similar issue.  None of the responses I've found have worked for it.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VeritoAnimus/m34rmmda/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>

    <style>

        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            font-size: 0px;
        }

        .my-block {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 31%; 
            min-height: 300px; 
            background-color: #0ff; 
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: .5%;
            padding: .5%;
            text-align: center;
            align-content: center;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .inner-block {
            display: inline-block;
            min-height: 140px; 
            background-color: rgba(90, 213, 25, 0.42);
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 4px auto;
            padding: 4px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .small-block {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 40px; 
            height: 40px; 
            background-color: #4cff00; 
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 4px;
            padding: 4px;

        }


    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="my-block">


    </div>

    <div class="my-block">
        <div class="inner-block">
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>
            <div class="small-block"></div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="my-block">


    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and here's what I'm getting and what I'm looking for

**Actual Result**
[image: Actual]

**Desired Result**
[image: Desired]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m34rmmda/1/)**. I assigned a width to `.inner-block` in the CSS:

```
.inner-block {
       width: 81%;
 }
```

Comment: the problem is that this is for an adaptive layout.  That doesn't help unless you know the exact size of the browser you're in. Since the block is percentage sized with fixed size wrapping content in the center, this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to achieve the desired result with only CSS. My solution to this would be, after load, change the width of `.inner-block`. I would use JS to calculate the current width of its parent `.my-block` and then find the next smallest multiple of 56px (size of the small boxes when accounting for padding and margin) to get the new size of the `.inner-block`. Otherwise, without a set width, `.inner-block` will expand to fill as much of the parent container as possible.

Comment: that's kinda what I was afraid of.  If the inner wrapper is not visible, would the be a way to achieve the desired effect on the content maybe?  My main concern with adding this to my existing js is that it's additional load that may take longer to render, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: Not that I can think of, although on mobile I'd probably either settle with center-aligned icons or wait and load the content after the initial page load so I'd be able to do those calculations behind the scenes rather than seeing a little flash of wrong alignment.